# MiKTeX 2.9 portable issue

Tags: installing, miktex

When I downloaded and updated MiKTeX 2.9 portable and try to change the paper size to `lettersize` under options, everything works fine. The paper size changes as desired but as soon as check for updates, it says that

```
miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7
miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7
miktex-dvips-base
miktex-pdftex-base-2.9
```

needs to be repaired. If I do the update the paper size is switched A4 size again. The story repeats again if change back to letter size. Why is this happening and can this be fixed?

Comment: Both the installation and any updates should be done with the same permissions.  Either both as admin or both as user.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. miktex is watching some packages for changes and reinstalls them when they have changed. In the portable version miktex has (probably) to change the original config file and so triggers the message. You should make a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is "normal," meaning that it has been the same for MiKTeX 2.9 Portable ever since I installed it. I believe it was the same for prior MiKTeX. When the packages are updated, the default size is "repaired" to A4.

However, I have never encountered a problem. My documents are created with page dimensions stated explicitly in the LaTeX code. The result is always what I specify (`lettersize`, or other). I do not know what would happen if I created a document without my own dimensions in the code.

That is: If your code uses a package that allows you to specify dimensions, and you actually do specify the dimensions, then the default page size (which always re-sets to A4 upon update) does not matter. This is not a problem with permissions, since I have seen it on Windows XP and Windows 7 alike.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Here's a [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: While this doesn't provide a fix for the problem (where I'm not sure a good fix exists), this is the most sensible thing to do. Besides—what if you shared your LaTeX document with someone eh had different 'defaults'? +1